# For loop to open multiple powershell windows

Tags: powershell

I'm looking for a way to open multiple powershell windows through a script. I tried with the following code, but it doesn't work.

```
for($1 = 1 ; $i -le 3; $i++)
{
    Start-Process powershell.exe
}
```

How can I reach this goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure where `$1` came from, change it to this:

```
for($i = 1 ; $i -le 3; $i++)
{
    Start-Process powershell.exe
}
```

and it'll work.

What's the end goal? Opening up new powershell processes will be slow and isn't usually necessary.

Comment: Hello @PMental thank you for your answer. How can I run your code in a powershell window? If I try, nothing happens. The goal is to run a different command in each window to download video from destreamer. I will ask other questions to get this goal.

Comment: How did you run your own code? You can just paste it in the shell, but the best way is obviously to put it in a script and save it to a .ps1 file.

Comment: Open ISE, and paste it in the "Scripting Pane" (the white area), and run it by clicking the "play" icon. No need to continue to copy and paste